# Preencher string com zeros

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Como verificar e preencher uma string caso seu tamanho seja menor que uma condição?
Por exemplo, preciso sempre ter uma string no tamanho de 8 ou 9.
Caso a string seja maior eu dou um substring pegando somente os 9 primeiros caracteres. 
Caso ela seja menor, preciso preencher com zeros "0" a esquerda.
Exemplo : '988554'  deverá ficar '000988554'. 
Importante é manter no formato string e não converter.

```
int TamanhoDaString= Regex.Replace(minhaString, "[^0-9]", "").Length; //ex: tamanho 5
                   int QuantDeZero = 9 - TamanhoDaString; // resultado = 4
                   int i;
                   string zeros = "0";



                 for (i = 1; i < QuantDeZero; i++)
                       {
                              // aqui engatei, pois como vou concatenar uma string com inteiro?
//resultado teria que ser zeros = "0000"
                        }
```

Comment: Já tentou `numero.ToString().PadLeft(9, '0')` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Poderia fazer dessa forma:

```
string a="988554";

a = a.PadLeft(8, '0');
```

Retorno seria: `00988554`

Comment: obrigada. Isso ai

Comment: se ajudou é só marcar como resolvida

Comment: Se o downvoter puder explicar o down ? pois resolve o problema com uma função pronta do c#

Comment: Está correta, vai entender esse povo.

Comment: Normal hehehehe

Answer (score 5):

Use o [`PadLeft()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net5.0#overloads). Passe quantos caracteres a *string* deve ter no total e qual o caractere quer que seja colocado, o padrão é um espaço em branco.

Sempre procure por funções prontas. A não ser que não resolva seu problema é melhor porque já foi testado.

```
using static System.Console;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        WriteLine("988554".PadLeft(8, '0'));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/PFVfzj). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o1BI4I). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/PadLeft.cs).

Comment: Isso ai chefe sem reinventar a roda

Comment: blz, não conhecia. Chegando no c# a pouco tempo.  Obrigada

Answer (score 2):

Poderia ser assim:

```
int tamanhoFinal = 9;
int numero = 988554;


Console.WriteLine(numero.ToString("D" + tamanhoFinal.ToString()));
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/5I69S4

Comment: opa.. isso ai.. Mas poderia explicar ?

Comment: o D especifica o valor Decimal. Fonte: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros